# Checkbox returns NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, radio-button, android-radiogroup

I'm developing a questioner in Android. The check box value should be passed to the next activity when the button is clicked. 
But half of the code works well while other half does not. This below code returns a nullPOinter exception.

```
Manufac_RG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                        int selectedID_manfac=Manufac_RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        manuf_RB=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedID_manfac);
                        manufac_DB=manuf_RB.getText().toString();

                        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewData.class);
                        i.putExtra("manifac",manufac_DB);

                    }
                });


            }
```

But this code works well

```
else if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("Trading"))
                {
                    trading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Trading_RG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                            if(Minerals.isChecked())
                            {
                                Sand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Gems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Others_minaral.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Sand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Gems.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Others_minaral.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                int selectedID_income1_trading=Trading_RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                                incomeSource1_trading=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedID_income1_trading);
                                is1_trading_DB=incomeSource1_trading.getText().toString();

                                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewData.class);
                                i.putExtra("trading1",is1_trading_DB);
                            }



                        }
                    });
                    manufac.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    agri.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

This is caught from the second activity. But it returns a NullPointer Exception. Can anyone help me with this please. Thanks in advanced.

This is my logcat

> 10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.isuru.socialdatagathering/com.isuru.socialdatagathering.ViewData}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-17 09:54:41.250:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-17 09:54:41.250:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 10-17 09:54:41.250:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-17 09:54:41.250:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(31698): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   com.isuru.socialdatagathering.ViewData.onCreate(ViewData.java:97)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 10-17
>   09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>   10-17 09:54:41.250: E/AndroidRuntime(31698):  ... 11 more 10-17
>   09:54:50.060: I/Process(31698): Sending signal. PID: 31698 SIG: 9

```
public class ViewData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView roofTV;
    TextView floorTV;
    TextView wallsTV;
    TextView toiletsTV;
    TextView roomsTV;
    TextView electricityTV;
    TextView waterTV;
    TextView statusTV;
    TextView ownershipTV;
    TextView loantakenforTV;
    TextView haveBankAccTV;
    TextView loansofOtherbanksTV;
    TextView currentEmpTV;
    TextView newEmpTV;
    TextView incomeSource1;
    Button Edit,Submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);

        roofTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_roofV);
        floorTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_floorV);
        wallsTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_wallsV);
        toiletsTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_toiletsV);
        roomsTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_RoomsV);
        electricityTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_electricityV);
        waterTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_waterV);
        statusTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_statusV);
        ownershipTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_ownershipV);
        loantakenforTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_loantakenforV);
        haveBankAccTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_havebankaccV);
        loansofOtherbanksTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_loansofotherbanksV);
        currentEmpTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_currentEmpV);
        newEmpTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_newEmpV);
        incomeSource1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_is1);

        Edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        Submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

        Edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        Submit.setOnClickListener(this);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String roof = intent.getExtras().getString("roof");
        String floor = intent.getExtras().getString("floor");
        String walls = intent.getExtras().getString("walls");
        String toilets= intent.getExtras().getString("toilets");
        String rooms = intent.getExtras().getString("rooms");
        String electricity = intent.getExtras().getString("electricity");
        String water = intent.getExtras().getString("water");
        String status= intent.getExtras().getString("status");
        String ownership = intent.getExtras().getString("ownership");
        String loantakenFor = intent.getExtras().getString("loantakenfor");
        String haveBankAcc = intent.getExtras().getString("havebankacc");
        String loansOfOtherBnks = intent.getExtras().getString("loansofotherbank");
        String currentEmp= intent.getExtras().getString("currentemp");
        String newEmp = intent.getExtras().getString("newemp");
        String agri1 = intent.getExtras().getString("agri1");
        String trading1 = intent.getExtras().getString("trading1");
        String manufac = intent.getExtras().getString("manifac");
        String services = intent.getExtras().getString("services");
        String employeed = intent.getExtras().getString("employeed");

        //for db
        String branch = intent.getExtras().getString("branch");
        String name = intent.getExtras().getString("name");
        String nic = intent.getExtras().getString("nic");

        roofTV.setText(roof);
        floorTV.setText(floor);
        wallsTV.setText(walls);
        toiletsTV.setText(toilets);
        roomsTV.setText(rooms);
        electricityTV.setText(electricity);
        waterTV.setText(water);
        statusTV.setText(status);
        ownershipTV.setText(ownership);
        loantakenforTV.setText(loantakenFor);
        haveBankAccTV.setText(haveBankAcc);
        loansofOtherbanksTV.setText(loansOfOtherBnks);
        currentEmpTV.setText(currentEmp);
        newEmpTV.setText(newEmp);
        if(!(agri1.equals("")))
        {
            incomeSource1.setText(agri1);
        }
        else if(!(trading1.equals("")))
        {
            incomeSource1.setText(trading1);
        }
        else if(!(manufac.equals("")))
        {
            incomeSource1.setText(manufac);
        }
        else if(!(services.equals("")))
        {
            incomeSource1.setText(services);
        }
        else if(!(employeed.equals("")))
        {
            incomeSource1.setText(employeed);
        }





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button_edit)
        {
            onBackPressed();
        }

        else if(v.getId()==R.id.button_submit)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with the logcat errors

Comment: Whats on line 97 on ViewData activity? It would be nice if you could update the whole ViewData Activity

Comment: ViewData activity is added

Comment: Could you point out the line number 97 in this class. That is where the exceptions is being generated

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line it seems like this line contain contain null value.

```
String manufac = intent.getExtras().getString("manifac");
```